# Rancher Single Docker Air-Gapped with Private Registry

Tags: rancher

I'm trying to start Rancher as a single docker in an air-gapped environment, as below. Looking at some error messages, the "local" cluster, which is **inside** Rancher, is trying to pull rancher/shell and it's failing, possibly because of the lack of authorization as our local repo needs it. How can we pass the registry credentials to the K3s running **inside** Rancher?

```
sudo docker run -d --privileged --restart=unless-stopped \
  --name rancher \
  -p 8080:80 -p 8443:443 \
  -v /home/devbox/certs:/certificates \
  -e SSL_CERT_DIR=/certificates \
  -e CATTLE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT_REGISTRY=private.docker.net \
  -e CATTLE_SYSTEM_CATALOG=bundled \
  private.docker.net/rancher/rancher:v2.7.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible by providing file `registries.yaml`, you can create something like

```yaml
configs:
  private.docker.net:
    auth:
      username: USER
      password: PASS
```

Then to your `docker run` command just add

```
-v ./registries.yaml:/etc/rancher/k3s/registries.yaml:ro
```

Everything should work